# Looking up a value from a table(section) that fits certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I know the function `LOOKUP` which can be used to look up a specific value for a given key.
However, I have data like this:

```
--+--A-+---B----+---C-----
1 | Key   Start    End
2 |  1    1.60     1.67
3 |  2    1.70     1.74
4 |  3    1.78     1.93
5 |  ....
```

For a given number "L", I would like to look up the key for which row the number is between the second (Start) and third (End) column. For example, the function should return 2 for L=1.71.

Something like:

```
=MAGIC_LOOKUP(AND(1.71 >= B2:B4, 1.71 <= C2:C4), A2:A4)
```

Comment: And which result you want for L=1.75? "Not found"? "Wrong value"? Or just #N/A?

Comment: You can try `=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$10,N($B$2:$B$10<=L2),N($C$2:$C$10>=L2)),"0;;""Not found""")`. It will return **string** of key, not integer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$4<=F2)*($C$2:$C$4>=F2),$A$2:$A$4)
```

[image]

Comment: Whilst technically this answer works for the question as posed, there are limitations to be aware of. First, it relies on the "Key" values being numeric. Second, it gives a result of 0 if there is no match. Third, unlike, INDEX/MATCH or the LOOKUP functions, it will return the sum of matching "Key"s (rather than the first matching "Key") if there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(key,MATCH(1,(start<=test)*(end>=test),0))
```

where

`key` is the range of ***Key*** values eg `A2:A5` and may include non-numeric values

`start` is the range of ***Start*** values eg `B2:B5`

`end` is the range of ***End*** values eg `C2:C5`

`test` is the ***Test value*** being looked up against intervals defined by `start` and `end`

The expression delivers the ***Key*** of the interval in which ***Test value*** falls. If no such interval exists the expression delivers `#N/A`. If ***Test value*** falls in more than one interval, the expression delivers the first listed ***Key*** that it falls within. If the arrays `key`, `start` and `end` are not all the same size the expression delivers `#N/A`.

[image]